# Rspec test for Rails method to return alphabetically sorted list of tags

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have one model class as listed here:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  def tags
    comments.map(&:tag).uniq.sort
  end
end
```

and below is the best rspec as per my understanding:

```
context 'tags' do
  let(:post) { Post.find_by_code('TX') }

  it 'returns sorted alphabetically list of available tags' do
    expect(post.tags).to eq(post.comments.map(&:tag).uniq.sort)
  end
end
```

Do we any better way to test it or even it is nor require to test.

Comment: You sould create a post, add comments to it, call the `tags` method and compare to a hardcoded ordered result pre processed based on the input you gave it. Now it's not testing anything, it's will always be true since you have basically the same code on both sides of the expectation.

Answer (score 2):

Your test code is merely a copy of your model code, so you're not really testing anything.

Rather, your unit test should rely on fixtures, and the expected answer should be hard-coded in the test.

Comment: Yes I have fixture of Post